# ArcGIS online - Arcade Code for Indicator element in the dashboard

Tags: html, gis, dashboard, indicator

I would love some help with arcade language to display data based on the 'if' logic.

I have added an indicator element into ArcGIS dashboard application. The indicator will display a numeric variable/value ‘cases’ and references the same numeric variable from to previous week ‘cases’.  I want to suppress the data if  the case count <10, (1-9) would say ‘suppressed’, case count 0 or 10+ would be displayed.

*The example data:*

**Date** 10/1/22  **Week** 1    **Cases** 5
**Date** 10/8/23  **Week** 2    **Cases** 10
**Date** 10/15/23 **Week** 3    **Cases** 8
**Date** 10/22/23 **Week** 4    **Cases** 4

The indicator box based on the value at or above/below reference value would look like this:

**Example 1** Indicator Box, Reporting on Week 2:
**Top text:** Cases
**Middle text** : 10
**Bottom text:** Suppressed (previous week)

**Example 2** Indicator Box, Reporting on Week 3:
**Top text:** Cases
**Middle text**: Suppressed
**Bottom text:** 10 (previous week)

**Example 3** Indicator Box, Reporting on Week 4:
**Top text:** Cases
**Middle text**: Suppressed
**Bottom text** : Suppressed (previous week)

Any help how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciate it!